# "Unable to initialize DirectX 9 device" when attempting to launch GTA V?

Tags: pc, technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v, windows-7, directx-9

I have GTA V on Steam and when I go to launch it after downloading, the loading screen comes up and and then goes to a message:

> Unable to initialize DirectX 9 device

I've tried asking R* for help but they don't care.

My Specs are:

- **CPU:** AMD 4.2ghz,
- **RAM:** 12GB,
- **GPU:** AMD Radeon R9 270X 4GB
- **OS:** Windows 7 64bit.

All of my drivers are up to date and I have my GPU enabled. I have tried launching with and without the GPU enabled and it gives the same message.

What can I do?

Comment: Try this first: On Steam, Right-Click the game -> Properties -> 'Local Files' tab -> Verify Integrity of Game Cache. This will download any missing files. It might not fix your problem, but it's the first step I usually try when debugging these sorts of errors

Answer (score 1):

Your PC still seems to have installed DirectX9. The message sent to you at launching the game means, that DirectX9 is not supported by GTA V. Try to upgrade your DirectX to the latest version.

Maybe [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/179113) will help you.

Comment: Windows 7 already has DirectX 11 installed. The message isn't saying that DirectX 9 isn't supported by the game, it's saying it tried to use DirectX 9 but failed.